# ANTLR warning multiple alternatives, how to understand it and how to get rid of it?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

fellow ANTLR experts, could you please explain me why this warning appears in ANTLWorks? How to understand this message and how to get rid of it in this particular case?

Example of valid input: abc "xyz def"
abc should be recognized as keywordExpr token and "xyz def" as phraseExpr.

[14:32:24] warning(200): TestExpr.g:12:4: 
Decision can match input such as "CHAR" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2

As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
[14:32:24] warning(200): /Users/imochurad/**Development**/antlr3/Grammars/TestExpr.g:12:4: 
Decision can match input such as "CHAR" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2

As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input

```
grammar TestExpr;

options {
output=AST;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree; 
}

expr
    :   kpExpr*;
kpExpr  :   keywordExpr|phraseExpr; 
keywordExpr
    :   CHAR+;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
phraseExpr
    :   '"' CHAR+ (' ' CHAR+)* '"';
CHAR    :   ('A'..'Z') | ('a'..'z');
INT :   '0'..'9'+;
NEWLINE :   '\r'? '\n';
WS  :   (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')+ {skip();};
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also i need blank space ' ' to be treated differently depending on what type of subexpression we have. If it is a phrase I want it to remain as a separator between words, but in case it is nor part of the phrase - skip it. Is it doable?

Answer (score 1):

As it is written, you grammar is ambiguous when parsing unquoted strings.  abc could be parsed as one `keywordExpr` (abc) or three (a, b and c) or even two.  I think you expect keywords to be separated by whitespace.  However, since you are skipping whitespace in the lexer, the parser cannot tell the difference between `abc` and `a b c`.

I suspect that `keywordExpr` and `phraseExpr` should be lexer rules:

```
KeywordExpr: CHAR+;
PhraseExpr:  '"' CHAR+ (' ' CHAR+)* '"';
```

`CHAR` should probably also become a fragment, to avoid accidentally generated a `CHAR` token when you have a single letter keyword.

With that change, abc is unambiguous in the lexer, since the lexer will use the longest possible match.

Regarding having spaces be treated differently, this works best if it is done in the lexer.  The above rule for PhraseExpr will correctly handle a space, since when the lexer encounters it, it cannot match the `WS` rule.  Handling it in the parser is much more complicated.